# Textbox doesn't follow text, when typing more than fits inside

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox, caret

I've encountered a weird bug, where textboxes wont follow when typing more than fits inside. Looks like this:

[image: textbox bug]

For reference, this is what a normal TextBox looks like in a blank project:
[image: textbox normal]

I've tried a few things, in order to fix it, like commenting out all textbox-related styles, put it in a blank view, but to no avail. Another interesting bit is that textboxes inside xceed datagrids look just fine.

I wish I had more info, but there's seemingly no reason, why they don't work, so any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Without any code there is nothing people can do for you...  Try a new empty solution, is there an issue ? if not issue is within your solution/project.  Styles can be applied other places on your project which affects your textboxes...

Comment: I know... it's not looking so good, is it.. I tried a new empty solution and it works fine. I also put in all my styles for good measure and it still works, so it's not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a ScrollViewer style, that was overriding the internal scrollviewer inside the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Setting TextBox.TextWrapping to WrapWithOverflow leads to such behavior.

Comment: Yep, but I've tested with all the wrapping options and the same thing happens.